# Finding $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^{\frac{\log(n)}{n}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

I was attempting to show that the power series

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{\log(n)}z^n
\end{equation*}

has a radius of convergence of $1$.

In order to do this I decided to use the $\alpha$ method.  This meant evaluating the limit

\begin{equation*}
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^{\frac{\log(n)}{n}}
\end{equation*}

I was able to prove that

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \dfrac{\log(n)}{n} = 0
\end{equation*}

but I realized that was necessary but not sufficient to show that the limsup in question is $1$.

I then was able to prove that

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1
\end{equation*}

However I could not figure out any way of using that fact either.

I realized I could rewrite this limit as

\begin{equation*}
\exp\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \dfrac{\log(n)^2}{n}\right)
\end{equation*}

However since I have not proven L'hôpital's rule, I have no way of evaluating this limit either.

This has left me pretty stuck.
I'm not sure how I could tackle this problem from here.
Where should I start for this limit?  Is there a way to do it without L'hôpital's rule?

I'd really rather not know the whole proof if possible.

Comment: Hint: $(\log n)^2 = (3\log n^{1/3})^2 \leqslant (3 n^{1/3})^2 = 9 n^{2/3}$

Comment: @RRL Wow, it seems abundantly clear to me now.  Feel free to write up an answer with that text and I'd be glad to accept it.

Comment: Just a note: because L'hospital's rule was needed to be proven without itself it means you can **always** calculate limit without L'hospital's rule, although from time to time it will be very hard

Comment: Not necessary. $\log n$ to any power is $o(n)$ in general.

Comment: @Holo I suppose I should have asked if there was a *reasonable* way to do it with without L'hôpital's rule.

Comment: You just need $\log x  < x$ for $x >0$.  If your definition is  $\log x = \int_1^x t^{-1} \, dt$ it is easy to see.  Or use the fact that $\log$ is monotonic and  $e^n > n$.

Comment: Yes, I actually proved that $\log n < n$ a little earlier.  I see how your proof can be extended to prove that $\log(n)^x = O(n)$ in general.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Since $n\gg1\implies\log n<\sqrt n$, you have$$n\gg1\implies n^\frac{\log n}n<n^\frac1{\sqrt n}=\left(\sqrt n^\frac1{\sqrt n}\right)^2$$and therefore$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^\frac{\log n}n\leqslant 1.$$And you already know that the reverse inquality holds.